# Identify unique attributes of a xml-file

Tags: r, xml

I need to identify all unique attributes of a xml-file to properly transform the xml to a data frame.

The following R-script allows to do the transformation. But only, if the attributes are known.

```
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
xml <- read_xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <movies>
              <movie Id="1" Name="Movie 1" IMDB="8,4" Date="2008-07-31T00:00:00.000" Views="649" />
              <movie Id="2" Name="Movie 2" IMDB="3,7" Location="El Cerrito, CA" Actor="Tom Hanks" />
            </movies>')

movies <- xml %>% xml_nodes("movie")
data.frame(
  Id = movies %>% xml_attr("Id"),
  Name = movies %>% xml_attr("Name"),
  IMDB = movies %>% xml_attr("IMDB"),
  Date = movies %>% xml_attr("Date"),
  Views = movies %>% xml_attr("Views"),
  Location = movies %>% xml_attr("Location"), 
  Actor = movies %>% xml_attr("Actor")
)
```

The output will look like this:

```
  Id    Name IMDB                    Date Views       Location     Actor
1  1 Movie 1  8,4 2008-07-31T00:00:00.000   649           <NA>      <NA>
2  2 Movie 2  3,7                    <NA>  <NA> El Cerrito, CA Tom Hanks
```

How is it possible to get a list of all unique attributes (the actual data is too long to check it manually)?

For this example, the desired output should look like the following list:

```
[1] "Id"
[2] "Name"
[3] "IMDB"
[4] "Date"
[5] "Views"
[6] "Location"
[7] "Actor"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your data:

```
Sample = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <movies>
              <movie Id="1" Name="Movie 1" IMDB="8,4" Date="2008-07-31T00:00:00.000" Views="649" />
              <movie Id="2" Name="Movie 2" IMDB="3,7" Location="El Cerrito, CA" Actor="Tom Hanks" />
            </movies>'
```

You can get most of what you want from `str_extract_all` in the `stringr` package and a regular expression.  At least as I did it, you need to clean up spurious = signs and then use `unique` to get rid of duplicates.

```
unique(sub("=", "", str_extract_all(Sample, "\\w+=")[[1]]))
[1] "version"  "encoding" "Id"       "Name"     "IMDB"     "Date"     "Views"   
[8] "Location" "Actor"
```

If you **don't** want to include the 'encoding' tag from the header, you can run

```
Sample = sub(".*(<movies.*?</movies>).*", "\\1", Sample)
```

first to select only the part with the movies.

Comment: It works like a charm. For my actual case, I only had to change the sub function to avoid extracting html information ("rel=", "href=", ...).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general approach using the xml2 package (this is loaded with rvest).  It works and a bit verbose (to provide a step by step guide), but I did not have time to optimized it.  See the code's comments for an explanation of how it works.

```
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)

xml <- read_xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <movies>
                <movie Id="1" Name="Movie 1" IMDB="8,4" Date="2008-07-31T00:00:00.000" Views="649" />
                <movie Id="2" Name="Movie 2" IMDB="3,7" Location="El Cerrito, CA" Actor="Tom Hanks" />
                </movies>')

#find all the movie nodes, returns a list of vectors
movies <- xml %>% xml_find_all("movie")   

#get all of the attributes and their values
attrs<-xml_attrs(movies)


#convert the lists into rows and merge the rows
# finally convert to a data frame
# based on recommendation from jstuhh
finalanswer<-bind_rows(lapply(attrs, as.list))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!. This general approach works perfectly fine and I am going to use it for my case. I have accepted G5W answer though, since he has the question rather answered.

Comment: I will upvote your answer as soon as it will be possible for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using the solution from G5W, the complete code to create the data frames (I only had to adjust the sub function to avoid extracting html information):

```
library(XML)
library(rvest)
library(magrittr)
library(stringr)

# 1. Read xml to "xml_document" / "xml_node"
data_xml <- read_xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                <movies>
                     <movie Id="1" Name="Movie 1" IMDB="8,4" Date="2008-07-31T00:00:00.000" Views="649" />
                     <movie Id="2" Name="Movie 2" IMDB="3,7" Location="El Cerrito, CA" Actor="Tom Hanks" />
                     </movies>')

# 2. Transform data to a string
data_char_all <- as.character(data_xml)

# 3. Remove 'encoding' and 'version' tag from the header
data_char_movies = sub(".*(<movies.*?</movies>).*", "\\1", data_char_all)

# 4. Extract all unique attributes
attr <- unique(sub("=\"", "", str_extract_all(data_char_movies, "\\w+=\"")[[1]]))

# 5. Create dataframe
# 5.1 Create xml_nodeset and assign all nodes
movies <- data_xml %>% xml_nodes("movie")

# 5.2 Create empty dataframe and assign values

df <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(ncol = length(attr), nrow = length(movies))), attr)

for (i in 1:length(attr)) {

  df[i] <- movies %>% xml_attr(attr[i])

# 6. Print result
df

  Id    Name IMDB                    Date Views       Location     Actor
1  1 Movie 1  8,4 2008-07-31T00:00:00.000   649           <NA>      <NA>
2  2 Movie 2  3,7                    <NA>  <NA> El Cerrito, CA Tom Hanks
```